# I have a Csv file with two columns.I want to convert this DataFrame to a JSON.I want 1st column of element as key & 2nd column of element as value

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

**file1.csv**

[This is a CSV file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFao0.png)

**Output should be like this:**

**Json:**

{"data_collected": "p-highlight bg-success",
"disclosure_of_information": "p-highlight bg-primary",
"opt_out": "p-highlight bg-warning",
"child_data_protection": "p-highlight bg-warning",
"ccpa": "p-highlight bg-warning",
"gdpr": "p-highlight bg-warning"}

Comment: are you looking for the `zip` function perhaps? `l1 = [1, 2]; l2 = [3, 4]; res = dict(zip(l1, l2));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm not too familiar with the `pandas` library myself either, so there might be an easier way.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [4, 5, 6]
})

df
#    a  b
# 0  1  4
# 1  2  5
# 2  3  6

dict(zip(df['a'], df['b']))
# {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6}
```